Is this set dense?
This is the problem I'm working on:
Find all functions $ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}^{*} $ such that for all $ x, y \in \mathbb{R} $, the following conditions hold:
\begin{cases}
f\left(x^{2}\right)=f(x)^{2}-2 x f(x) \\
f(-x)=f(x-1) \\
1<x<y \implies f(x)<f(y)
\end{cases}
We can show that $f(n)=n^2+n+1$ for all integers $n$.
Additionally, we can extend this to $2^n$-th roots of positive integers using the first condition.
I would like to extend this to real numbers greater than $1$ by using monotony and showing that the set $S=\{m+\sqrt[2^n]{k} \mid m \in \mathbb{Z},n,k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in $(1,+\infty)$.
I'm not too familiar with the concept of density, so  I'm not sure if this actually works. Any help is greatly appreciated.

If $0$ is not included in $\mathbb N$ then $m+\sqrt[2^n]{k} \ge 1+1=2$

Oops, I edited the question, $m$ can be negative.

Let  $1<a<b<\infty$. Let $m$ be an integer such that  $a-m>1$. Then the length of the interval $((a-m)^{2^{n}}, (b-m)^{2^{n}})$ exceeds $1$ for $n$ large enough. Any interval of length larger than $1$ contains an integer $k$, and , in this case, $k$ is postive. This gives $a<m+\sqrt[2^n]{k}<b$ and we have proved that your set is dense in $(1,\infty)$.

The function $f(x)=2^x$ is a continuous function that maps $(0,\infty)\to (1,\infty)$.  Given $y>1$, there exists $x\in (0,\infty)$ such that $2^x=y$.  Given $\epsilon >0$, there exist positive integers $n$ and $\ell$ such that $|2^{\frac{\ell}{2^n}}-y|<\epsilon$.  Let $k=2^{\ell}$ and then $$|k^{\frac{1}{2^n}} - y| = |2^{\frac{\ell}{2^n}} - y| < \epsilon.$$ Therefore, the set $\{ \sqrt[2^n]{k}: k,n\in \mathbb{N} \}$ is dense in $(1,\infty)$.  The parameter $m$ is not needed to get density.
